# PHP: Separating Business logic and Presentational logic, is it worth it?

Tags: php, html, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I use templating system in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436014/why-should-i-use-templating-system-in-php)

I was just curious as to how many developers actually do this?

Up to this time I haven't and I was just curious to whether it really helps make things look cleaner and easier to follow. I've heard using template engines like Smarty help out, but I've also heard the opposite. That they just create unnecessary overhead and it's essentially like learning a new language.

Does anyone here have experience with templates? What are your feelings on them? Are the helpful on big projects or just a waste of time?

On a side note: The company I work for doesn't have a designer, there are just two developers working on this project charged with the re-design/upgrade. I also use a bit of AJAX, would this have issues with a template engine?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436014/why-should-i-use-templating-system-in-php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not only does this practice make the code **look** cleaner, it also has many long term and short term benefits.

You can never go wrong with organizing code. First off it makes it much easier to maintain and easier to read if someone else has to pick up after you. I have worked with Smarty before and it is nice, it keeps the designers work from interfering with the program code.

Using template systems and frameworks would make it much easier to accomplish tasks. There is a rule of thumb you can follow which is DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Frameworks help you achieve this goal.

You may want to look into [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), this is the model that these frameworks are based off of. But you could implement this design structure without necessarily using framework. Avoiding the learning curve. For frameworks like [Zend](http://www.zend.com), the learning curve is much greater than some other ones.

I have found that [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/) is fairly easy to use and they have some VERY helpful video tutorials on their website.

Best of Luck!!

Answer (score 6):

Actually it's the business logic that needs to be separated from the views. You can use php as a "template language" inside the views.

You can use ajax on any template engine i think.

*Edit*

My original response addressed the question whether to use a template engine or not to generate your html.

I argued that php is good enough for template tasks, as long as you separate business logic from presentation logic.

It's worth doing this even for simple pages, because it enables you to:

- isolate the code that is the *brain* of your application from the code that is the *face*, and so you can change the face, without messing with the brain, or you can enhance the brain without braking the looks
- isolate 80% of bugs in 20% of your code
- create reusable components: you could assign different presentation code to the same business code, and vice versa;
- separate concerns of the feature requests (business code) from the concerns of the design requests (presentation code), which also usually are related to different people on the client side, and different people on the contractor side
- use different people to write the business code and the presentation code; you can have the designer to handle directly the presentation code, with minimal php knoledge;

A simple solution, which mimics MVC and doesn't use objects could be:

- use a single controller php file, which receives all requests via a .httpdaccess file;
- the controller decides what business and presentation code to use, depending on the request
- the controller then uses an include statement to include the business php file
- the business code does it's magic, and then includes the presentation php file

Comment: More or less what I was going to say. I think PHP was originally developed to be a sort of templating language, so it's not really necessary to add another layer, but *do* separate out any non-presentational code.

Answer (score 2):

PHP *is* a template engine (or if you prefer, a hypertext preprocessor). When HTML is mixed heavily with PHP logic, it does become very difficult to maintain, which is why you would have functions defined separately to build various parts and simply build the page from short function calls embedded in the HTML. Done like this, I don't see much of a difference between Smarty and raw PHP, other than the choice of delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

Separation of concerns is a very important tenant to any type of software development, even on the web. Too many times I have found that people just throw everything into as few files as possible and call it a day. This is most certainly the wrong way to do it. As has been mentioned, it will help with maintainability of the code for others, but more than that, it helps you be able to read the code. When everything is separated out, you can think about easily.

Code Ignitor, I have found, has been the easiest to learn framework for working with PHP. I pretty much started my current job and was up and running with it within a few days, from never having heard of it, to using it pretty efficiently. I don't see it as another language at all, either. Basically, using the framework forces me to organize things in a manageable way, and the added functionality is anlagous to using plugins and such for jQuery, or importing packages in Java. The thought that it's like learning another language seems almost silly.

So, in short, organize organize organize. Keep in mind, though, that there is a level of abstraction that just becomes absurd. A rule of thumb is that a class (or file in our case) should do one thing very well. This doesn't mean it is a class that wraps around print, but takes a string, formats it using a complex algorithm and then prints it (this is just an example). Each class should do something specific, and you can do that without any framework. What makes MVC great, though, is that it lets you organize things further, not just on the single class level, but on the level of "packages", being Model, View, and Controller (at least in the case of these frameworks; there are other ways to package projects). So, now you have single classes that do things well, and then you have them grouped with similar classes that do other things well. This way, everything is kept very clean an manageable.

The last level to think about once you have things organized into classes, and then packages, is how these classes get accessed between packages. When using MVC, the access usually will go Model<->Controller<->View, thus separating the model (which is usually database stuff and "business" code in the PHP world), from the view (which usually takes information from the user, and passes it along to the controller, who will then get more information from the model, if necessary, or do something else with the input information). The controller kind of works like the switchboard between the two other packages **usually**. Again, there are other ways to go with packaging and such, but this is a common way.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty and other php template frameworks really do nothing more than compile to PHP anyway, and they also cache their results in most cases to allow for faster processing.  You can do this all on your own, but if you ever look at the compiled templates that Smarty generates, and compare to the original Smarty template you create, you can see that one is far more readable than the other.

Answer (score 0):

I write mostly mod_perl these days and started using templates (HTML::Template) halfway through our ongoing project. If I had to make the decision again, I would use templates right from the start - rewriting later to use templates is kind of tedious, though rewarding because you get nicer and cleaner code. For anything bigger than 2-3 pages in php, I would also use some template engine.

Answer (score 0):

One big advantage of a templating engine such as Smarty is that non-developers can use it to embed the necessary logic that is used on the front-end (one really can't separate logic and display on all but the simplest sites). However, if the developer is the one maintaining the pages then using PHP would be preferable in my opinion.

If you separate out large logic blocks and maintain a consistent patten for looping and for-each flow control statements (i.e. don't use print statements, or only use print statements for one-liners, etc.) Then that should be okay.