# PHP Pass variable up the page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I came across someone asking the question,

> How can I pass a variable up the page (on the same page?).

I had a think about it but couldn't think of how to do it myself, so I was wondering if it is even possible?

So what he was trying to do was change the value of `$a` at the top of the page at the same time as the bottom value of `$a`.

Is it possible? If so how?

Thanks in advanced.

```
<?php
echo("Begining " . $a);
?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Test Variables</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST">
<input type="TEXT" name="testf" size="10">
<input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "submit"></form><?php
if ("submit" == $submit) {
$a = $testf;
echo( "Bottom " . $a);
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Edit:

After seeing answers, maybe it can be done with jquery, ajax or javascript?

Comment: You can use references, but if you `echo` something using variable value, it will not change in that string, of course.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll need to move the `if` statement to the top, and any variables you calculate that need to be in the if statement also to the top.

Something like:

```
<?php
if ("submit" == $submit) {
    $a = $testf;
}
echo("Begining " . $a);
?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Test Variables</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST">
<input type="TEXT" name="testf" size="10">
<input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "submit"></form><?php
echo( "Bottom " . $a);
?>
</body></html>
```

It's considered a good practice to have all the logic before you start outputting the HTML anyways. Your HTML should ideally have as less logic as possible.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/95027/320615 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088791/320615

Comment: I understand, but lets say I couldn't move that to the top of the page, how could I then do it?

Comment: @SamHam, you can use [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start), but that would make the code even more unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably bend over backwards to make that work somehow.

But the real answer is to handle all your business logic **before** you start outputting any HTML. You need to decide at **the beginning of your code** whether the current request is a form submission or not and set variables and HTML templates accordingly. Never mix business logic into the middle of your HTML templates.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer in this thread so far. @Sam Ham. You should give this answer a try instead of trying to hack around with bad practice workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `$_POST['testf']` and `$_POST['submit']` variable.

And also check if it exists with isset : [php manual isset](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php)

```
<?php
echo("Begining " . $a);
?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Test Variables</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST">
<input type="TEXT" name="testf" size="10">
<input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "submit"></form><?php
if ("submit" == $submit) {
$a = $_POST['testf'];
echo( "Bottom " . $a);
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it in PHP, but you can't change HTML once it's fully loaded using javascript (and jquery to make it easier).

EDIT : ok I read your code a bit quickly the first time :
I don't understand the `echo` before the `<html>` tag, doesn't seem right. Also you want to give the value of a POST var to `$a`, so just :

```
if(isset($_POST['testf'])) {
    echo $_POST['testf'];
}
```

Comment: Would you know how or what to search for?