# PHP Include With Variety

Tags: php, html, include, title

I have a `php include` statement for the "head" of my website.

I am using the following code to call `head.php`...

```
<?php 
    include '../components/head.php' 
?>
```

And in my `head.php` I have the following code...

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="/style.css">
    <title>Dummy Code</title>
</head>
```

How can I make it change the title by having a variable in my page on my page like `Dummy Code | About` being the title if I have `$title = "About"` on my webpage.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: WAT ? Simple `<title>My site - <?php echo $title;?></title>` ?

Comment: put the variable $title in the <title> tags

Comment: you must set `$title` before include `heaad.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all belong to the global namespace, so you just can do this:

```
<?php 
    $title = 'about';
    include '../components/head.php' 
?>
```

head.php:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="/style.css">
    <title>Dummy Code | <?=$title; ?></title>
</head>
```

But make sure that you understand: this is very simplified code and **should not** be used on the production projects.

Comment: What do you mean by _this is very simplified code and should not be used on the production projects._?

Comment: I mean you shuld avoid of including files with html code and use some template engines instead.

Comment: I don't understand, I am very new to PHP and HTML.

Comment: Okay, a few words. It's a bad practice when PHP code is combined with HTML. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436014/why-should-i-use-templating-system-in-php