# Writing code using HTML-escaping to avoid cross site scripting attack

Tags: php, html

I am a PHP newbie. This is part of a gallery code. I recently read about SQL injection and cross site scripting attack, I am trying to avoid that by html escaping on dynamically produced data. I am not sure if I am heading in the right direction here. I created an array with URL parameters then a function for HTML escaping. Can you critique this code and let me know what I am doing wrong please?

```
$parameters_new = array('name' => $name,'pcaption' => $caption_array[$new]);

function html_escape($input, $encoding)
{
    return htmlentities($input, ENT_QUOTES, $encoding);
}

$result_final .= '<div class="limage"><table><tr><td><table class="image"><tr><td><a href="' . html_escape('gallery.php?' . http_build_query($parameters_new), 'UTF-8') . '">
<img src="'. $img_dir . '/' .$photo_filename.'"  alt=" ' . $photo_keywords . '"></a>
<div class="caption">'.$photo_caption.'</div><div class="excerpt">'.$photo_description.'</div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><div class="underline"></div>;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. It belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Agreed on appropriateness to SO. However, well done for actually thinking about security in the first place - too many people don't.

Comment: Some good reading over here if you're interested ~ https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: I think that the function `http_build_query($parameters_new)` will encode all special chars to a %xx encoding, rendering the custom function useless. **EDIT** It will, check here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51c7c43ca83b255482bf05edc5fb51e83777dd1d

Comment: Thanks Phil and Ismael..

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you that use a template system or you create your own.

Template systems, like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), could [scape your vars](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl)

You could see this question: [Why should I use templating system in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436014/why-should-i-use-templating-system-in-php)

Comment: I really have a lots to learn here. Thank you for giving me a place to start Avara...