# Is it a good idea to make a PHP website using only DOM?

Tags: php, dom

Good morning,

I'm making a website in PHP, the "classic way" (mixing html and php). However as the website grows, the code gets ugly. So I was wondering if making the whole website with DOM is a good idea. DOM produces, I think, cleaner code, allow faster modifications in the code . etc.
"DOM" refers to the functions you can find here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php (createElement, getElementById ...)

Is it a good idea to use only DOM ? Or is it a crazy idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean 'using only DOM?'?

Comment: yeah, please clarify what you mean. Maybe you want to look into templates instead?

Comment: Why is this closed? It's a valid question. Although has been answered in real life some 10-15 years ago, but still

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371037/php-building-xhtml-output-with-dom-pros-and-cons

Answer (score 2):

No, both ideas are bad. Mixing code and HTML is just terrible. Trying to build whole HTML using DOM is way too inefficient. The way to go is to separate logic and presentation. Later should be done using templates.

Use web framework implementing [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). There are quite [a few of them for PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#PHP).